# Struggling with type Document on seeding. There was an issue. Reason: Could not infer type of value

Tags: aqueduct, postgresql-json

I have an column defined like this:

```
@Column(nullable: true)
Document openHours; // List "openHours": ["Tuesday - Sunday: 11.00 - 21.00"],
```

In my migration file i use seed():

```
@override
Future seed() async {
const sClientSQL = ...
```

and the json part that throws me out, is:

```
"openHours": [
    "Monday - Friday: 17.00 - 22.00",
    "Saturday: 14:00 - 23:00",
    "Sunday & Holidays: 11:30 - 22:00"
  ],
```

Error in Terminal looks like:

```
Seeding data from migration version 1...
*** There was an issue. Reason: Could not infer type of value '[Monday - Friday: 17.00 - 22.00,    
Saturday: 14:00 - 23:00, Sunday & Holidays: 11:30 - 22:00]'.. Table: null Column: null
```

Documentation says:

```
Document    map or list (Map<String, dynamic> or List<dynamic>)
```

JSON Looks ok to me, but obviously in this context it's wrong. So what am i doing wrong here? I couldn't find an example on how to code the json part for type Document in aqueduct.

Thank all and regards
Antonio

[Edit 4]

Here is a shortened example of the query that:

```
const sClientSQL = 'INSERT INTO _Clients (name, owner, address, contacts, openhours, dayOff, description) VALUES (@name, @owner, @address, @contacts, @openhours, @dayOff, @description)';

await database.store.execute(sClientSQL, substitutionValues: {
  'name': 'Dolce Vita',
  'owner': 'David Driss',
  'address': {
    'street': 'Johannisstr. 3',
    'zipCode': '54290',
    'city': 'Trier'
  },
  'contacts': {
    'phone': '0651 94 90 40',
    'fax': '0651 43 23 2',
    'mail': 'info@dolcevita.de'
  },   
  'openhours': [
    "Montag - Freitag: 17.00 - 22.00",
    "Samstag: 14:00 - 23:00",
    "Sonntag & Feiertag: 11:30 - 22:00"
  ],
  'dayOff': '',
  'description': 'Alle Speisen und Getränke sind inkl. MwST. Extrazutaten werden gesondert berechnet'
});
```

[Edit 1]

**Further Information:**

substitution values is as Map.

I used double quotes, and changed it to single quotes, that didn't have effect.

[EDIT 2]

Tried out complex map in dartpad and created a gist to show:

[Gist to Dart Maps sample](https://gist.github.com/acambule/376b9565afdc4a0cb39df39fa3c078b7) put the code in to dartpad.

**Result** The map as it is, is valid.

[EDIT 3]

1. I removed all json columns to secure it works. Success.
2. Added one json column, the first example i showed before. Same problem
3. Tried to make a manual insert of jsonb column. Success.

So, only the `await database.store.execute` command doesn't want my json type literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from a user on an other channel i finally figured out, how to get it work.

The magic is all about using the right syntax and it's been a lot trial and error, wonder where to find the docs about it?

- When using multiline then use three single quotes ''' at the beginning and the end
- Inside the multiline expression use double quotes for the json

**Working Examples**

all following "fields" in substitutionValues are jsonb columns in database

- *address* and *contacts* are examples for json objects
- *openhours* is an example for a json array of strings, multilined
- *fess* is an example for a json array of objects, multilined

```
await database.store.execute(sClientSQL, substitutionValues: {
  'address': {
    'street': 'a street',
    'zipCode': '123456',
    'city': 'mycity'
  },
  'contacts': {
    'phone': '12345678',
    'fax': '12346578',
    'mail': 'info@mydomain.com'
  },         
  'openhours': '''[
    "Monday - Friday: 17.00 - 22.00",
    "Saturday: 14:00 - 23:00",
    "Sunday: 11:30 - 22:00"
  ]''', 
  'fees': '''[
    {"delivery": 2.00, "minOrder": 7.50, "location": "all"},
    {"delivery": 2.50, "minOrder": 9.50, "location": "here"},
    {"delivery": 2.50, "minOrder": 9.50, "location": "there"}
  ]''',
```

I think that with these we get all complexity done.